# Connect synchronously to MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Normally you would do something like:

```
var db = new mongo
    .Db('test', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017), {w: 1})
    .open(function (error, database) {

        if (error) throw error

        console.log('Connected to database test')
    })
```

I, however, want to connect to mongodb synchronously. So I'd need a method I can use in this way:

```
var db = new mongo.openDb('test', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017), {w: 1})

console.log('Connected to database test')
```

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's best to embrace the asynchronicity with Node.js rather than fight it.

Comment: @ JohnnyHK The advantage of asynchronicity is that the code does not block and also that it's possible to handle errors properly. If your app depends on the database for further execution and is supposed to crash and throw an error anyway, you can as well skip the whole callback/asynchronous hassle…

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/tree/master/lib), it connects the database without callback.  Here is the example from its github:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_tests", {native_parser:true});
db.bind('article');
db.article.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/), then you could do something like what you outlined above.